# Cannot find my packagename in file explorer?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am using ADT plugin in Linux os .I am creating an android application which uses Sqlite database. I have viewed my database table many times using SQLite Browser .But now in file explorer when I click the Data it is not listing the **data/your package name/databases/yourdatabse.db** .How can I get the package name in file explorer?
I want to view my database table.Is there any other way to find it?[image]

Comment: is this real device or Emulator ?

Comment: i am using real device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its Real device we can not See Data folder inside data

but if its Emulator

Go to

data>data> Search for your package name>database>yourdatabse.db

[image]

Search your package name. Then inside database folder yourdatabse.db will be created.

Answer (score 1):

If it is **non-rooted** real device then you can not See Data folder inside data.But all the **emulators are rooted device** .So in Emulator

Go to

data>data> Search for your package name>database>yourdatabse.db

Answer (score 0):

Go to

```
data>data> Search for your package name>database>yourdatabse.db
```

[image]

**Search** your package name. Then inside **database** folder **yourdatabse.db** will be created.